# Update Google Charts Values With AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, charts

I'm trying to update a Google Chart with data from a database using AJAX.

The updates should happen when I select an option.

However, it doesn't update anything...

**Here's the chart:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']}); google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

<?php include("chartdata.php");?>
]);

var options = {
    animation: {duration: 1000, easing: 'out', "startup": true},
    vAxis: {minValue: 0},
    pointSize: 4,
    pointShape: 'circle'
};

var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);

// FILTER CHART

$("#chart-selector option").click(function() {
    var selectname = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url:"include/chartdata-filter.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{select_name:selectname},
        dataType:"text",
        success:function(chart)
        {
            alert(chart); // WORKS
            chart.draw(google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([chart]), options); // DOESN'T WORK
        }
    });
});}
```

**This is the select field. So when I select one it should update the chart:**

```
<select id="chart-selector" name="select_name" onchange="chartSelect()">
<option>List Item 1</option>
<option>List Item 2</option>
</select>
```

When I select one of the options I get the output correctly in the alert. The output in the alert looks something like this (from chart.php):

```
['Date', 'Column 1', 'Column 2'],
['2016-10-01', 0, 0],
['2016-10-02', 1, 2],
['2016-10-03', 3, 4],
['2016-10-04', 5, 6],
['2016-10-05', 7, 8],
['2016-10-06', 9, 10]
```

**Also, when I manually paste this data into the AJAX success function it works as well:**

```
chart.draw(google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'Column 1', 'Column 2'],
    ['2016-10-01', 0, 0],
    ['2016-10-02', 1, 2],
    ['2016-10-03', 3, 4],
    ['2016-10-04', 5, 6],
    ['2016-10-05', 7, 8],
    ['2016-10-06', 9, 10]]), options); // THIS WORKS
```

But obviously pasting it manually doesn't make any sense since I want to update the data onchange.

**So to recap:**

1. I have select options.
2. When I select one of the options the data should be pulled from the databse (WORKS).
3. The data is pulled correctly in the alert, but it isn't updated in the chart. When I paste in the code manually it works onchange. So the problem is probably somewhere in here:

   chart.draw(google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([chart]), options);

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance for anyone who has an idea!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's because you're using `dataType: 'text'` so your `chart` variable is a string rather than an array (i.e. `"[1, 2, 3]"` instead of `[1, 2, 3]`). It's showing up correctly in the alert because the alert is displaying the contents of the string. You need to deserialize the array first. Try this:

```
var arr = JSON.parse("[" + ajaxResponse.replace(/'/g, '"').replace(/,$/g, '') + "]");
chart.draw(google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arr), options);
```

**Edit**: Runcorn's answer includes an important detail I forgot to include. If the text returned from your ajax call doesn't have single quotes escaped with a `\` or replaced with double quotes, it will fail.

**Edit 2**: Updated to include the relevant snippet for the working code. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jek8h5mw/8/) with it working correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your response.

You mean like this?

`$.ajax({ url:"include/chartdata.php", method:"POST", data:{select_name:selectname}, dataType:"json", success:function(chart) { chart = chart.replace(/'/g, '"'); var arr = JSON.parse("[" + chart + "]"); chart.draw(google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([arr]), options); } });` 
Doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're using `JSON.parse()` then leave the `dataType` as `"text"`. Also, you shouldn't need to include the square brackets inside of `JSON.parse()` if you're surrounding `arr` with brackets when calling `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable()`

Comment: I changed the `datatype:` to ``"text"` and removed the brackets but I still get no repsponse. I also tried different combinations but still nothing. When I do it the way @Runcorn suggested I get this error message: **"Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string"**. Any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: It's difficult to say for sure what the issue is without knowing exactly how `chart` is formatted. Can you use developer tools in your browser and break on the first line of the success function (i.e. `alert(chart);`) and type `chart` into the console to see exactly how it's being returned from your ajax call?

Comment: Also, can you show me _exactly_ what you tried when you got that error?

Comment: To get the error I paste exactly what @Runcorn suggested into the success function: `$.ajax({url:"include/chartdata.php",method:"POST",data:{select_name:selectname},dataType:"text",success:function(resultantAjaxResponse){var resultantAjaxResponse="['Date', 'Column 1', 'Column 2'],['2016-10-01', 0, 0],['2016-10-02', 1, 2],['2016-10-03', 3, 4],['2016-10-04', 5, 6],['2016-10-05', 7, 8],['2016-10-06', 9, 10]";resultantAjaxResponse=resultantAjaxResponse.replace(/'/g, '"'); var arr = JSON.parse("[" + resultantAjaxResponse + "]");chart.draw(google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([arr]), options);}});`

Comment: Error in the console: **SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 8 column 1 of the JSON data** 
`drawChart/</<.success()
n.Callbacks/i()
n.Callbacks/j.fireWith()
y()
.send/c()`

[link](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/JSON_bad_parse)

AJAX returns: `['Date', 'Column1', 'Column2'],['2016-10-01', 0, 0],
['2016-10-02', 0, 0],
['2016-10-03', 0, 0],
['2016-10-04', 0, 0],
['2016-10-05', 0, 0],
['2016-10-06', 0, 0],
['2016-10-07', 0, 0],`

Might the problem be trailing commas or single quotes (though they work when pasted manually)?

Comment: I took exactly what you pasted in the first of your 2 recent comments and removed the brackets from `arr`, and it worked. I'm updating my answer with the corrected code.

Comment: Hm, when I do it this way `success:function(ajaxResponse) {

var arr = JSON.parse("[" + ajaxResponse + "]");
chart.draw(google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arr), options);

}` I get this error: **SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data** and this AJAX response `['Date', 'This month', 'Last month'],['2016-10-01', 0, 0],
['2016-10-02', 0, 0],
['2016-10-03', 0, 0],
['2016-10-04', 0, 0],
['2016-10-05', 0, 0],
['2016-10-06', 0, 0],
['2016-10-07', 0, 0],` Thanks for the effort

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear - take a look at the fiddle. You still need to replace the single quotes.

Comment: When I use your updated code, I get this error: **SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 8 column 1 of the JSON data
**. When I use the code from the fiddle, I get this error: **SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 37 of the JSON data**. For both I get this response: `['Date', 'This month', 'Last month'],['2016-10-01', 0, 0],
['2016-10-02', 0, 0],
['2016-10-03', 0, 0],
['2016-10-04', 0, 0],
['2016-10-05', 0, 0],
['2016-10-06', 0, 0],
['2016-10-07', 0, 0],`

Comment: Is what you posted the exact data that's being returned from the ajax call? The fiddle works so the data you're receiving from the server must be different than what I have there. Is the trailing comma included in the ajax response? Because that would certainly be an issue. Ideally, you would update the server code that's giving you that response to remove the trailing comma, but if that's not an option, then add `.replace(/,$/g, '')` after the first `replace` to remove the last comma. I'll update my answer again.

Comment: According to the console that's what I'm getting (with trailing comma) `['Date', 'This month', 'Last month'],['2016-10-01', 0, 0],['2016-10-02', 0, 0],['2016-10-03', 0, 0],['2016-10-04', 0, 0],['2016-10-05', 0, 0],['2016-10-06', 0, 0],['2016-10-07', 0, 0],['2016-10-08', 0, 0],`. I changed the code to this `success:function(ajaxResponse) {var arr = JSON.parse("[" + ajaxResponse.replace(/'/g, '"').replace(/,$/g, '') + "]"); chart.draw(google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arr), options);}`, now I get this error **SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 9 column 1 of the JSON data**

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you. I updated the fiddle in my answer to use the data you provided here and got it working, so take a look and see if there are any differences between what I did and what you're trying. Otherwise I'm not sure what else I can do.

Comment: Here's the code I use `success:function(ajaxResponse) {chart.draw(google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([JSON.parse("[" + ajaxResponse.replace(/'/g, '"').replace(/,$/g, '') + "]")]),options);}`, now I'm getting this error from the chart itself: **Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string**. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are passing test(String) to `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable` which instead requires array object. The AJAX response you get is a plain text which you would need to convert to Javascript array. Please follow the following steps to do so,

```
var resultantAjaxResponse="['Date', 'Column 1', 'Column 2'],['2016-10-01', 0, 0],['2016-10-02', 1, 2],['2016-10-03', 3, 4],['2016-10-04', 5, 6],['2016-10-05', 7, 8],['2016-10-06', 9, 10]";
//Convert String to JSON Parse-able form
resultantAjaxResponse = resultantAjaxResponse.replace(/'/g, '"');
//Convert to Javascript array
var arr = JSON.parse("[" + resultantAjaxResponse + "]");
```

You can now use the `arr` as,

```
chart.draw(google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([arr]), options);
```

Please note that I haven't tested this code but this should fix the issue you are getting. Also, I would suggest you to return JSON instead of text in AJAX Response so that it would be more convenient and simple to map result to array.

Comment: @A. Damond Thanks for your response.

You mean like this?

`  $.ajax({
   url:"include/chartdata.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{select_name:selectname},
   dataType:"json",
   success:function(chart)
   {
    chart = chart.replace(/'/g, '"');
    var arr = JSON.parse("[" + chart + "]");
   chart.draw(google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([arr]), options); 
   }
  });`

Doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: just use `dataType : "text"` for now ... and see if that helps.

Comment: When I do it exactly the way you say I get this error: **Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string**. When I do it the way I commented above I get no response at all. I changed `datatype:` to `"text"` and I also tried removing the brackets but I still get no response. Any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Here's the code I use `success:function(ajaxResponse) {chart.draw(google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([JSON.parse("[" + ajaxResponse.replace(/'/g, '"').replace(/,$/g, '') + "]")]),options);}`, now I'm getting this error from the chart itself **Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string**. Any ideas? Thanks